# How to create a cage for baking?

Tags: texture-baking

I have various problems with baking, especially normal maps. I heard it's better to have a cage, but how do I create a cage?

Here is a picture of how it looks.

[image: Screenshot of attempt to create a cage]

Comment: Could you please add some more details?  Like what kind of problems you are having.

Comment: i leterallydont know how to create a cage :D

Comment: @TheCycleOfBlend But what has gone wrong with the normal baking that makes you think you need a cage?

Comment: welli have artifacts on my normall map and weird stuff of course i could add it to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [polycount wiki](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Normal_map#Working_with_Cages):

> Most normal map baking tools allow you to use a distance-based raycast. A ray is sent outwards along each vertex normal, then at the distance you set a ray is cast back inwards. Where ever that ray intersects the high poly mesh, it will sample the normals from it.
>
> Unfortunately with a distance-based raycast, split vertex normals will cause the bake to miss parts of the high-res mesh, causing errors and seams.
>
> [image]
>
> Some software allows you to use cage mesh option instead, which basically inflates a copy of the low-poly mesh, then raycasts inwards from each vertex. This ballooned-out mesh is the cage.

So the **Cage mesh is a low-poly mesh defining how far will be the rays cast**. Its good for fine control, but usually you can get away with just properly set Ray Distance in the Baking panel and having smooth shading.