# Normal Map Distortion Problem

Tags: normals

This is my first time going through the process of modeling something start to finish and I'm running into a problem with the normal map.

I created a high and low poly version, the low has uvs. Now I'm trying to bring back the detail with a normal map but it doesn't seem to be coming through right. What is causing the distorions on the original?

[image]

Comment: could it be that you haven't set Smooth shading on the entire object?

Comment: An odd shape like that might benefit from [using a cage](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21206) when baking. Also check the ray distance isn't too large.