# How do I bake normals correctly?

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I baked two meshes. one is low quality the other is high quality.
But the result of bake is wrong... 
what is the problem?
[image]

Comment: You might find this question helpful: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21186/how-to-create-a-cage-for-baking

Comment: Try increasing the Ray Distance.